# How to get html code in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, html-parsing

I need to parse some site -> get some html code from this site -> put this code in NSString -> 
 `[web loadHTMLString:someNSString baseURL: nil]`;

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Check the methods in `MWFeedParser`,

```
- (NSString *)stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.m